# jQuery live() works with jQuery 1.8.3 & below but not with 1.9.1 or 2.0

Tags: jquery, live, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.8, jquery-2.0

I've been using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js for a while now and everything has been fine, but 1.8.3 got quite old so I've decided to move to the latest jQuery. And suddenly a few things stopped working: [Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) and part of my own jQuery code (that shows additional data under every slide of a slider).

Can you help me figuring out what's wrong? Or maybe it's not worth moving to jQuery versions above 1.8.3? Check the Jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show" data-show="first">SHOW</a>
<a href="#" class="show" data-show="second">SHOW</a>

<div id="first">First paragraph.</div>
<div id="second">Second paragraph</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(".show").live("click", function (e) {
    var slide = '#' + jQuery(this).data('show');
    jQuery(slide).slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

CSS:

```
div { display: none; }
```

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ABrna/

Try changing jQuery to 1.9.1 or 2.0 and hit Run. Script stops working. Why?

Comment: The `.live()` method has been removed. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: "TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace "live" from jQuery 1.8.3 to jQuery 1.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479608/how-to-replace-live-from-jquery-1-8-3-to-jquery-1-9)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ see the hint in the corner? deprecated 1.7 removed 1.9

Comment: `-1` This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 4):

The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Answer (score 3):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

[Doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent to `.live()` using delegation with `.on()` is:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".show", function (e) {
    var slide = '#' + jQuery(this).data('show');
    jQuery(slide).slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But you shouldn't set delegation at document level but use instead closest static container.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery 2.0 deprecate the live function. You can find more information in http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: It was deprecated before that time.