# No method live error with jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code worked fine with jquery 1.7.2. But it doesn't with jquery 1.9.1. It gives an error with "Uncaught TypeError. Object [object Object] has no method 'live'.

How can I fix the problem?

[image]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tablecont = $("#tablesorter1");
    var module = "category";

    function updateitem()
    {    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "http://localhost/tangen2014/index.php/category/admin/Ajaxgetupdate", 
            complete: function(data)
            {
                tablecont.html(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

        //on submit event
    $(".changestatus").live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var id =href.substring(href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "http://localhost/tangen2014/index.php/kaimonokago/admin/changeStatus"+"/"+module+"/"+id,
            complete: function()
            {
                updateitem();
            }
        });  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery live() works with jQuery 1.8.3 & below but not with 1.9.1 or 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543309/jquery-live-works-with-jquery-1-8-3-below-but-not-with-1-9-1-or-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)**

> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead

So you need to use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** here:

```
$('#tablesorter').on('click', ".changestatus", function(event){
    // Your code here
});
```

It's also better to delegate the events to the closest static parent instead of document level for better performance.

Comment: I don't think there's any significant *performance* reason to pick a close parent, but there are other good reasons. Bubbling is done in native browser code, so I doubt there's any measurable difference in bubbling all the way up to the document.

Answer (score 1):

The `.live()` method has been deprecated since like forever, and it was yanked completely in 1.9.

Use:

```
    $(document).on('click', ".changestatus", function(event){
```

It doesn't *have* to be `$(document)`; it can be any handy container element. That is, any element that's a parent of your ".changestatus" elements.

The `.live()` method was a good idea implemented badly. For a while there was `.delegate()`, which worked more like the modern all-in-one `.on()` does with three parameters.