# ASP.NET Code generated by Ajax.ActionLink stopped working after Upgrading to JQuery 2.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-2.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 app that I have upgrade to JQuery 2.0.1, unfortunately this has had some unpleasant side effects. ([More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479608/how-to-replace-live-from-jquery-1-8-3-to-jquery-1-9))

Currently I have only one outstanding issue: The HTML link generated by @Ajax.ActionLink no longer calls the appropriate js code, but instead is treated as a regular link by the browser.

The page in question contains the following js files:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript">script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
```

I have had to manually update the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` file to resolve another issue (replace `live` by `on`).

The `Ajax.ActionLink` looks as follows:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "InputResources",
                new { id = Model[i].ID },
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "DELETE",
                    Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                    OnComplete = "window.location.href='/Projects/InputResources/" + ViewBag.ProjectID + "'"
                })
```

The HTML generated seems to look sound:

```
<a href="/InputResources/Delete/5" data-ajax-method="DELETE" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?" data-ajax-complete="window.location.href='/Projects/InputResources/2'" data-ajax="true">Delete</a>
```

Can anyone suggest what js files and how I need to modify in order to get this link working correctly again?

Comment: I have same issues as you and would love to see solution on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is what solved it for me:**

This will update your jquery validation script to latest version:

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation
```

This will update your jquery unobtrusive validation script to latest version:

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive
```

Make sure both are included in your page after jquery library,
 it will not work if you don't do this.